# Этимология слова "стеб"

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Сейчас часто на молодежном жаргоне беззлобный смех над кем-то называют *стёбом*. А откуда это слово пошло?

Comment: Мне как-то не казалось что стёб такой уж безобидный и беззлобный...

Comment: Стёб он разный. Но "обидный и злобный" - это уже не совсем стеб. 
Да и вообще "стеб" не обязательно "над кем-то". Даже обычный эпатаж - тоже своего рода стёб. Попробую уточнить в соответвующих кругах точные значения.

Comment: В 60-х годах мы уже употребляли это слово: очень престижно было уметь стебаться, стибун был душой компании,стебош это была ,порою, коллективно поддерживаемая оргия смеха и хохота.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще слово **СТЕБ** появилось не сейчас, а гораздо раньше. Стеб как особый стиль общения, как специфический язык интеллигентской и молодежной "тусовки" возник и развился в 1970-1980 гг. [здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/gramota/ruspress/28_606)
Есть мнение, что слово СТЕБ этимологически связано с глаголом *стебать* (хлестать, стегать, бить плеткой, прутом). Эта версия вполне реалистична, ср.: стебаться - "хлеско, иронично высмеивать что-то или кого-то". Сам глагол **стебать** предположительно  происходит из **стегать** под влиянием слова *стебель* (стегают обычно как раз каким-нибудь стеблем).

В Викисловаре приводится еще одна версия, согласно которой слово СТЕБ происходит из арго хиппи. Возможно, от лит. stebinti «удивлять, поражать, изумлять» (традиционно стёб осуществлялся в присутствии осмеиваемого субъекта с целью вызвать его замешательство).
Однако эта версия мне кажется менее правдоподобной, поскольку заимствования из литовского языка крайне редки. Если честно, мне ни разу не встречались :-))

[Замечу в скобках, что сведения о литовских соответствиях часто приводятся в этимологических словарях для сопоставления, так как считается, что литовский язык сохранил изначальные фонетику и морфологические особенности прототипического индоевропейского языка и тем самым представляет интерес для лингвистического исследования. Существует мнение, что среди современных языков литовский является наиболее близким праиндоевропейскому. Но данные сведения никак не могут помочь объяснить литовское происхождение слова СТЕБ:-))]

Comment: У меня стойкое ощущение, что слово стеб я слышал раньше 1970, в раннем детсве, причем не в столицах. 

ЗЫ "Плюсик" от меня не только и даже не столько за версии, сколько за "литовские заимствования в скобках".

Comment: Спасибо за плюсик "литовским заимствованиям в скобках". Желание выучить литовский, по крайней мере, разобраться с его грамматикой только укрепилось :-))

Comment: Снимаю шляпу. Я на такие подвиги не способен. Но уже одно понимание места литовского в общей и.-е. "картине мира" дорогого стоит.